# How to receive both binary and JSON in same GET request in SparkJava?

Tags: java, spark-java

I have a [SparkJava](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html) application and know how to receive JSON and binary data via separate requests. Is there a way to setup a Route to accept both at the same type? I'm interested in receiving an image and some related text about that image. The goal is to prevent two requests being sent from the client(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically you cannot send 2 types of content per response. I don't know if there is a hack that can simulate 2 types of content per response... If there is none then you have to send two requests from the client. One will respond with the JSON and the other one with the binary data.

As you can see in the following [link](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html) only one content-type is possible, which can have multiple parameters.

Hope this helps.